# how to shuffle in itertools.cycle()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-itertools

I'm using the `itetools` in the data generator in tensorflow based network training. The main framework is as follows:

```
def data_generator(filenames, batch_size):
    files= itertools.cycle(filenames)
    while True:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            filename = files.next()
            # read data into X and Y
            ....

        yield np.array(X), np.array(Y)
```

When using this data generater,

```
train_input = data_generator(train_filenames,batch_size=1)
for ep in range(num_epochs):
    for _ in range(num_train_samples):
        image_batch, label_batch = train_input.next()
        loss_val = sess.run([loss_op], feed_dict={})
```

My question is: in general, we need to shuffle the training data after each epoch, how to shuffle in this circumstance? Thanks.

Comment: You can't shuffle an infinite generator (like `itertools.cycle`) but it seems like what you actually want to do is simply draw a random selection of filenames, which you can do with the `random` module

Comment: is `filename = random.choice(filenames)` equivalent?

Comment: Hi, @Chris_Rands, thanks for comment! You mean I could modify the `filename=files.next()` to pick the filename randomly? Then the filename is a random selection. If I understood correctly.

Comment: Hi, @georgexsh, thanks for comment! yeah, I think so. But how to guarantee to visit the filenames once during one epoch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not modify a `cycle` iterator once created, so you have to make a new one in each "epoch" loop:

```
def data_generator(filenames, batch_size):
    filenames = filenames[:] # make a copy
    random.shuffle(filenames)
    files = itertools.cycle(filenames)
    ...

for ep in range(num_epochs):
    train_input = data_generator(train_filenames, batch_size=1)
    ...
```

Comment: What if I need to control the training iteration number instead of epoch ? For example, I need to train for exactly ten iterations instead of 2 epochs ?

Comment: @coincheung this is a general answer against itertools usage.

Comment: So could I actually use itertools to control the exact iteration number ?

Comment: @coincheung please ask a new question, because i don't know how your code works.